# Powershell Remote Session, Can't seem to set the screen resolution?

Tags: powershell, screen-resolution, powershell-remoting, powershell-cmdlet

I have been trying to set the screen resolution of my remote machine via a Powershell remote session for a while now.  I can get the resolution from the        Get-DisplayResolution cmdlet and I get the following back.

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -Session $rs
[vm.company.com]: PS C:\Users\username\Documents> cd \
[vm.company.com]: PS C:\> Get-DisplayResolution
1024x768

[vm.company.com]: PS C:\> Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1440 -Height 900 -Force
setres will now attempt to apply the following display settings:   

  Width:          1440                       
  Height:         900

The settings passed in could not be applied to the graphics device.

[vm.company.com]: PS C:\> Set-DisplayResolution -Width 1024 -Height 768 -Force
setres will now attempt to apply the following display settings:

  Width:          1024
  Height:         768

The settings passed in could not be applied to the graphics device.

[vm.company.com]: PS C:\>
```

This is very frustrating because I can't even seem to be able to change the display resolution to what it currently is set to because I keep getting the error

> The settings passed in could not be applied to the graphics device
>   .

I've tried this on my machine locally and it appears to work just fine.  Here is the version of Powershell that displays on the remote machine.

```
[vm.company.com]: PS C:\> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.34209
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.17065
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2


[vm.company.com]: PS C:\>
```

Does anyone know a way around this problem?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The command you mentioned is probably returning the resolution of your session rather than the console, which doesn't support changing (it's likely that there isn't a resolution at all and it's just returning a default, or the resolution that the profile is set to use when logged on). Try changing the resolution on the console and see if this is reflected in your session.

Comment: You can't actually change the resolution in a remote session. You should be able to set the defaults, but not the resolution of the active GUI session. Even remote desktop sets the resolution on the connection, the display properties are disabled.

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel how do I set the resolution on the console as you've suggested?  This is a virtual machine running on a vm-ware server.

Comment: @Eris can you tell me more about that?  What do you mean by your statement:

_> You should be able to set the defaults, but not the resolution of the active GUI session._

I'm trying to change the screen resolution for the purposes of End to End Testing with Protractor.  I'm sure I can't be the first person in the world to have this particular problem.

Comment: I'd recommend setting the resolution using the VMware tools, not from within windows. If you use `vmrun runProgramInGuest` to run the application in the guest instead of a remote powershell session, it should do what you need. I'd suggest asking about this over on PowerUser or ServerFault though, as it's more of an admin task, not really programming.

Comment: @Eris Thanks, I understand it is not really _programming_ per say but I am the developer that is in charge of setting up our continuous integration (ci) server up to run these end to end test.  That is why I was asking the question.  Thanks for the information!

Comment: Apparently after a lot of searching, I have found that I will be unable to change the size of the "System Desktop" which is all that I have access to when using Powershell remoting.  I was able to get around this issue using a Windows RDP session but I consider the solution is shoddy at best.  It involved creating a lot of code around using Remote Desktop Client and the Win32 calls to simulate what I needed to do to kick off the end 2 end tests in the resolution that I wanted to.  _Ultimately the solution is the fix the end to end test and the software to run in a 1024x768 screen resolution_.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can only change the resolution of a remote host at connection time.

Depending on the tool you use, look for remote desktop size settings, for example on the command line :

```
mstsc /w:1440 /h:900 /v:remote_host
```

Answer (score 1):

While this is not a direct answer to the question and ultimately it's not as solid and clean a solution as I would have liked.  I found a work around that will allow me to perform the end to end testing on a remote machine that can be launched from our CI server. [Automate your remote desktop sessions]https://outofmemoryexception.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/automate-your-remote-desktop-sessions/ .  Hopefully you will find it useful in your scenarios also.  I remain open to better solutions.